# When I convert a pivot table to formulas I get #GETTING_DATA instead of values

Tags: sql-server, excel, cube, powerpivot, dax

When I convert a pivot table to formulas I get `#GETTING_DATA` instead of values in the valuecells of the former pivot table.

The row labels and column labels are showing fine. But all the value cells are showing `#GETTING_DATA`.

Here is an example of a formula that is showing the value #GETTING_DATA

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel";$B$11;$B$12;$B$13;$B21;C$19;Slicer_LastActualMonthName2)
```

What could the reason for this be?

More information:
All of the cell referenced above are filters, row labels or column labels. The pivot table is based on a power pivot model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting calculation mode to automatic in Excel resolved the problem.